# HttpConnection: Getting null response

Tags: android, httpconnection

When I hit GET service using url with parameter 
http://example.com/API/SignUpAPI?Password=abc&MobileNo=123.
It give status 200 and response is "Success".

```
URL url=new URL(strings[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(methodType);
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            server_response = readStream(connection.getInputStream());
            Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
        }
```

But

When I hit GET service using url with parameter 
http://example.com/API/SignUpAPI and parameter sent by using OutputStreamWriter. It give status 200 and response is null.

```
 connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod(methodType);
        if(params!=null){
            String reqParam = "";
            StringBuilder buildParam = new StringBuilder();
            for (String paramKey : params.keySet()) {
                if (buildParam.length() > 0) {
                    buildParam.append("&");
                }
                buildParam.append(
                        URLEncoder.encode(paramKey, "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(params.get(paramKey).toString(), "UTF-8"));
            }
            reqParam = buildParam.toString();
            connection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent","REST");
            System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*//*");
            connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            connection.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();
            try (OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream())) {
                wr.write(reqParam);
            }
        }

        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
            server_response = readStream(connection.getInputStream());
            Log.v("CatalogClient", server_response);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: you should be using retrofit + rxjava to handle networking cause its currently the most popular networking library. httpurlconnection is a dinosaur :P

Comment: In both examples we cannot see the vslue of methodType. Please put the used,/fsked urls in your code.

Comment: For the rest: any questions? And pretty unclear which problem you have. Or if you only create a problem.

Comment: `When I hit GET service` ???? Where can you hit such?

Comment: Value of methodType is GET